# GIT / bitbucket - how to exclude 1 commit on bitbucket's master AFTER it was pushed

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've pushed 2 local commits onto bitbucket.org.

I would like to ignore, delete, forget the 1st one. So pretend it never existed.

But in my Pull request, both appear, I've got 2 bullet points.

Just talked to a colleague that stopped by: it appears the I need to initiate a Rollback. The Master repository Admin can only Merge or not, but not discard a commit I did?

Thank you

Comment: Update: in Visual Studio 2013, Team Explorer => history, I'm right clicking my yesterday's commit and click "Revert". 

But I've got a "Cannot revert the commit because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before reverting the commit again."  
Well I don't have anything un-committed, my "Changes"  =>  "Included Changes" is at Zero. My "Excluded Changes" has got 48 items that I'd like to keep this way, so hopefully there's nothing I need to act upon the "Excluded changes" ?

Answer (score 1):

First and most safe way is to revert this commit:

```
git revert [your_bad_commit]
```

It will add new commit which will undo changes of chosen one. Then push to master as usual.

Second way works only if you want undo last commit. Do

```
git reset [last_good_commit] --hard
```

By this you will discard all commits added after chosen one. Then push to master with --force flag:

```
git push -f
```

**Warning**: you lost all changes in master that not in you local master branch, so be careful with force push!

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. From Visual Studio 2013 when I right-click the commit and click "Revert", it produces this error message "Cannot revert the commit because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before reverting the commit again.".  But I've got no uncommitted changes.. I do have about 48 EXCLUDED changes, but I'm not going to "undo" these, some are DLL and this is meaningless. Now, on the bitbucket team repository, my push hasn't been merged. Could it be the reason for this message?  In fact, all I need is to "Un-Push", so Bitbucket master to ignore this commit.

Comment: Easiest way to see the state of you working dir is to run: `git status`

Comment: Thank you, it's blank of any change or un-commited work, so I don't know where Visual Studio sees some changes to be committed or undone. I don't have any.

Comment: I'm stuck in that I cannot revert as I need. At least from VIsual Studio. And there is no detail as for the claim, I've got a "Show output from: " set to "Source -Control - Git". But this is blank, empty!  I'll probably bypass Visual Studio and try everything from Bash GIT?  But I'd rather know the reason behind this Visual Studio "Cannot revert the commit because there are uncommitted changes", and subdue Visual Studio into executing that revert!

Comment: Yes, if you try it in native shell, even if you get some error, much more people will be able to help you, because it have much wider usage.